# Calling alias with other alias + parameters

Tags: bash, alias

i was trying to summerise grep while being able to give another command with parameters but I cannot figure out how to make it work
What I am doing is this

```
alias pac='sudo pacman'

grp(){
     $1 | grep $2 | less
}
```

And trying to run any of these:

```
grp 'pac -Q' nvidia
grp "pac -Q" nvidia
grp (pac -Q) nvidia
```

but i am failing in everyone of them,any advice?

TL;DR:
Basically the tittle
or
Trying to make `command -XYZ` acceptable as an $NUM value or any other form usable the same way

Comment: You'd have to use `eval "$1"` but that's definitely not recommended. What's wrong with `pac -Q | grep nvidia` ?

Comment: pipe is in an awkward position in my keyboard so im trying to use it the least amount of time as possible,also the reason i am shortening it to grp is because i use grep quite a lot and the reason i posted this here(since grep is not enough of a reason for me to do it)is because I have a few other alias examples i want to shorten tbh
I just cant find the "googleable words" to describe this phenomenon that I am trying to approach so I decided to post here

Comment: Aside: `| less | grep` is decidedly sub-optimal. Did you mean to do `| grep | less`? Or are you relying on `less` pre-processing some how?

Comment: You see,I have no idea why i wrote less first and then grep...thank you for pointing that out,though nothing changes in output since code was grep first then less,my post was wrong sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a workaround. In bash, when an alias expansion ends with a space, the next word is also considered for expansion. So if I had:

```
alias foo='echo ' bar=hello
```

Then `foo bar` would result in `echo hello` being run:

```
$ foo bar
hello
```

With this, you can use an alias for the `grp` function to have its first argument be considered for alias expansion, and then modify `grp` accordingly to use the *last* argument as the pattern:

```
grp () {
  local pat="${@: -1}"
  "${@:1:$#-1}" | grep "$pat" | less
}
alias grp='grp '
```

Then:

```
$ grp pac -Q nvidia
lib32-nvidia-utils 440.82-1
nvidia-dkms 440.82-2
nvidia-settings 440.82-1
nvidia-utils 440.82-2
opencl-nvidia 440.82-2
```

Of course, this won't work with complex aliases, for example those that use pipelines:

```
$ alias foo='bar | cat'
$ grp foo nvidia
cat: nvidia: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That's not only in bash. Any standard shell should do that, and do it recursively: `sh -ic $'alias foo="echo " bar="hello " baz=nasty\nfoo bar baz'` => `hello nasty`.

Comment: @localuser ah, [it is standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01). Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```bsh
grp() {
    local grep_pattern=$1
    shift
    # remaining args are the command:
    "$@" | grep "$grep_pattern" | less
}
```

And invoke it like:

```
grp nvidia pac -Q
```

Comment: hmm,unfortunately it dose not work with pac(another alias defined earlier on .bashrc ) but does work with sudo pacman -Q,further testing will be done for now,will update on any findings and wourld appreciate any further input as well

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I dun goofed.  Nevermind.

A little old I know, but assuming you don't need to be widely portable across various older shell implementations, process substitution (instead of pipes) is one way to do this directly.

```
grp() {
  less -f <( grep ${@:2} <( $1 ))
}
```

invoke as `grp 'pac -Q' nvidia`, as requested.

Comment: (1) Look at the title of the question.  It is specifically about passing one alias to another.  Did you do this ***after defining*** **`pac`** ***as an alias**?*  I tried it and got `bash: pac: command not found`.  (2) Why ``${@:2}`` instead of ``$2``?

Comment: ...huh.  To be honest, I tested it outside of a function definition... but you're right that makes a difference.  That's awkward, my bad.  (${@:2} is the positional parameters starting from $2)

Comment: Thanks; I know what `${@:2}` ***is**;* I was asking why you thought it was appropriate, when the question is about `$2`.